# JS : Biggest element of an array, less than a given variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given :

```
var array = [1,2,5,10];
var limit = 8;
```

I am looking for a way to find the biggest element of the array, less than the limit 8. something like :

```
Math.max(array, "while < limit");
```

I tried :

```
Math.min(Math.max(array), limit)
```

which does not work in all cases for array and limit, obviously.

**EDIT :**

The input array is not necessarily sorted :

```
var array = [10,-10,10,-10];
var limit = 5;
```

Expected result is -10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var array = [1,2,5,10];
var limit = 8;
alert(Math.max.apply(Math, array.filter(function(x){return x <= limit})));
```

Comment: Your answer is the shortest one, and it looks like what I expected at first. Does anyone see any drawback using this method ?

Comment: @Vincent:- I don't think there is any drawback with this. Also to bring to your notice that your edit with the new array seems to be wrong `var array = [10;-10;10;-10];` should be `var array = [10,-10,10,-10];` and this works as well. https://jsfiddle.net/4dk0mop8/

Comment: OP asked for *less than* instead of *less or equal*, so it should be `x < limit`. Otherwise, nice answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can [**sort**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), [**filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and then [**pop**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

```js
var array = [1,2,5,10];
var limit = 8;

var largest = array.sort().filter(item => (item < limit)).pop();

console.log(largest);
```

Comment: And if the array is `[10,7,5,3,2,1]`?

Comment: @epascarello I edited my question to include the fact that my array is not sorted

Comment: @epascarello, nice catch! Thanks for the tip. Updated my answer

Comment: @Vincent This approach is not nearly as efficient as the ones proposed by the other answers. 1) Sorting is a rather time-consuming operation which is only needed to make the rest of this work. 2) sorting is done *in place* thereby altering the array's order itself. 3) `.filter()` adds just another loop through the entire array to it. Because the array is sorted in ascending order it should be looped through right-to-left breaking out of the loop once the limit has been reached.

Answer (score 2):

You can either just do a simple for loop, you can filter all numbers less than the max and sort and max, or you can use reduce which is just like doing a for loop.

for loop (could use forEach)

```js
var array = [1, 2, 5, 10];
var limit = 8;
var result = array[1];
for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i] <= limit && array[i] > result) {
    result = array[i];
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Filter with Max

```js
var array = [1, 2, 5, 10];
var limit = 8;

var result = Math.max.apply([], array.filter(function(val) {
  return val < limit
}));
console.log(result);
```

Reduce

```js
var array = [1,2,5,10];
var limit = 8;

var temp = array[0];
var result = array.reduce( function (num, val ) {
    return val > num && val <= limit ? val : num
}, temp);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try in this way:

```
var array = [1,2,5,10,7];
var limit = 8;

var max=0;
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{   
   if(array[i] > max && array[i] < limit)
      max=array[i];
}

console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [1,2,5,10];
var limit = 8;
var closest = null;

array.forEach(function(el){
  if (el <= limit && (closest == null || (limit - el) < (limit - closest))) {
    closest = el;
  }
});

alert(closest);
```